# Which ones are appropriate?: "an office staff", "an office staff member", "an officer", or "to work in an office"?

Tags: word-usage

In the dictionaries:

> **[staff](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/staff)** [countable, uncountable] the people who work for an organization
>
> You say **a staff member** (or **a member of staff** in British English) or **an
>   employee**, when talking about one person on the staff. ✗Don’t use **a
>   staff** to refer to one person.
>
> **[officer](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/officer)**: someone who is in a position in an organization or the government
>
> a prison officer
>
> the chief medical officer
>
> the organization's public information officer
>
> The document must be certified by the proper officer of the state.
>
> **[office staff](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/office%20staff)**: professional or clerical workers in an office

Let say, I am an average accountant mostly work in an office of an certain company.

**Which of the followings are appropriate**?

*I am an office staff*

*I am an office staff member*

*I am an officer*

*I work in an office*

Comment: "which of the following"  (not followings).

Answer (score 2):

1 and 3 are definitely wrong. 1 is wrong for the reason given in the dictionary: staff is a collective noun. 3 is wrong because "an officer" means something different than "someone who works in the office"; it has various meanings in military, legal, government, and corporate contexts, but always means someone in an official role--that is, a role with defined powers and duties. If someone just says, "I am an officer," I'd assume they're a police or military officer.

To me as a native American English speaker, 2 sounds stilted. "I am a member of the office staff" sounds good, if formal. 4 sounds totally natural, but it has a more general meaning, because you're no longer talking about a specific office, which is what you're looking for. "I work in the office of X Accounting Firm" sounds fine, as does simply, "I work for X Accounting Firm," which implies that you're a member of the office staff.

Comment: what about "I am a White-collar worker"?

Comment: People never describe themselves that way. It’s generally used to talk about the labor market or refer to a hypothetical worker.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, people don't speak about the *place* that they work (office) as much as they speak about the *type of work* that they do or *company* they do the work for.

If someone asks: "Where do you work?", responding by saying "I work in an office" sounds like you are avoding the question. Respoding by saying "I work for X Company as a Job Title" sounds more natural. (Example of how this would sound in a real conversation: "I work for Google as a Software Engineer")